# Should one use multiple catch blocks or catch base Exception and handle it with is keyword?

Tags: c#

I was working on a university project and did a funny action with exceptions handling.

I had a piece of code in a `try {  }  catch {   }` block. It could throw two types of exceptions and each one of the should be handled **differently**.

Without even thinking about it, I wrote code like this:

```
try
{
    SomeAction();
}
catch(Exception _Ex)
{
    if(_Ex is NullReferenceException) 
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else if(_Ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException) 
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Hovewer my professor has said that this is a strange way to do this and asked why haven't I used this construction:

```
try
{
    SomeAction();
}
catch(NullReferenceException _Ex)
{
    DoSomething();
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException _Ex)
{
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

I couldn't disagree with him that this way is also valid - maybe even simpler than my way. All this got me thinking - both solutions are correct and do the same thing.
If so, which one should be used as a better practice?

I personaly think that the method using `is` is a bit better, because it allows the programmer to generally handle the exception situation and AFTER that handle each `Exception` derivative individually. Apart from that, I like the way it looks more "syntactically nice".

On second hand, the multiple `catch` version is the way it is supposed to work according to the C# reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/0yd65esw.aspx).

Do you think that both those methods are acceptable, or should one use only one of them? 
If so, which one "wins"?

I know it's not the most important problem on Earth, but it just made me curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your professor is right. **Ideally, you should catch exceptions only which you are interested in.**

**Flaw in first approach is, it will catch all unintended exceptions say `ArgumentNullException`.** In this case ideally application should crash with unhandled exception. If you want to log the information then you should rethrow all other exceptions after logging.

---

This code is equivalent to what your professor suggested:

```
catch(Exception _Ex)
{
    if(_Ex is NullReferenceException) 
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else if(_Ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException) 
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
    throw;
}
```

Comment: FYI `StackOverflowException` is uncatchable atleast above .net2.0

Answer (score 3):

Your two examples do significantly different things. The first one captures **any** Exception and only handles the cases NullReferenceException and ArgumentOutOfRangeException, **silently ignoring all other cases**. The second case only captures and handles NullReferenceException and ArgumentOutOfRangeException and leaves any other exception to be handled by higher catch block up the chain. Second case is correct, first is likely not. And this is probably why you should always code like the second, so you don't fall into the trap you set yourself in the first case.